# Remove from superview during completion removes it earlier

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this code, for example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         [self animateMenuOut:menu];
                     }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [menu removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
```

Instead of animating, however, it will just disappear from the view. Removing the `[menu removeFromSuperview];` line makes it work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your -animateMenuOut method is of the fire-and-forget nature... as soon as your animation code triggers, it works in a background thread and your code execution continues (going to completion). This is a feature to avoid UI blocking as far as I know.

Hope this was of some help.

Josh.

Comment: Code in the completion block is executed once the animation has finished (or been canceled, in which case the finished paramater will be `NO`).

Comment: I know UIView provides this:
'[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];'

Comment: It's advised not to use that in iOS4 and above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with this code.
Some ideas:

1. Problem inside `animateMenuOut`
2. Bad redrawing performance. Low FPS & duration 0.3 sec => you see no animation. Have you tried increasing duration?
3. You block the main thread after starting the animation.